# How to make a two column accordion in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried wrapping half the panels in col-sm-6. It successfully dissects the accordion into two columns, but the collapsing functionality breaks. They do not auto-collapse anymore.

Any ideas on how to get this to work correctly in Bootstrap 3?

[Here](http://bootply.com/84122) is the code that I am working with. Notice how they don't autocollapse when another heading is clicked.

Comment: I do not find the problem you mentioned, see: http://bootply.com/83750

Comment: @BassJobsen Your code introduces some other problems, like strange shifting when some of them are clicked.

Answer (score 3):

First the reason why your example (http://bootply.com/84122) will be broken. In your example your wrap your div.panel in an div.col-xs-6. The plugin don't allows this wrapping. The div.panel 's should be direct children of your div#accordion. Where the relation will be defined by `data-parent="#accordion"`.

The above follows from collapse.js line 51: `var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .panel > .in')`. At the moment i don't think this is a bug cause this strict nesting allows nesting of panels without problems.
When you replace this line with `var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find(' .panel > .in')` (remove the > before .panel) your example will work well. (solution 1).

In my comments i suggested to use this: http://bootply.com/83750. This will work without changes in the javascript cause the col-x-x classes are add to the div.panel in stead of wrap them. You mention problems like strange shifting, you could prevent this by adding a clearfix (`<div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>`) after each second panel.
In your case you could leave the `hidden-xs` cause you use col-xs-6 classes (never collapse).

Without grid collapse:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
          Collapsible Group Item #4
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
</div>
```